# Сохранение настроек в ресурсы

Tags: android

Подскажите, как правильно сохранить строку в ресурсный файл. Объясню на моём примере: в текстовом редакторе необходимо при запуске открыть файл, который использовался в последний раз. И надо, само собой, держать где-то имя этого файла. Preferences не подходят, да и в другой файл записывать это имя не хочу. Думаю, лучше сохранить в ресурсный файл strings.xml, да вот не знаю как. Прошу предложить разумное решение в данной ситуации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Запись:

```
any = this.getSharedPreferences("any", MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor e = any.edit();

e.clear();
e.putString("path", path);
e.commit();
```

Чтение:

```
String path = any.getString("path", "");
```

Comment: нельзя ли использовать для таких целей getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) ? Просто у меня в приложении уже используется предпочтение 
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
из которого я получаю настройки для отображения текста. А получается, что придётся создавать 2 предпочтения.

Comment: Конечно, можно. `getDefaultSharedPreferencesName` - это тот же `getSharedPreferences` с именем `context.getPackageName() + "_preferences"`.

Comment: Для чего использовать метод clear? Разве без него не будет перезаписываться значение строки?

Comment: Метод clear (полная очистка настроек) использовать необязательно, он взят просто для примера.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете изменить данный файл программно(по крайней мере я не встречал такой возможности нигде). Ресурсы подставляются на этапе компиляции, для улучшения быстродействия. 
Выше предложили выход - хранить в настройках опции, другой - создать произвольный файл xml, положив его в assets и разбирать его как угодно.